# Spacy alignment differences when training with DocBin vs custom data reading and batching

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I am just getting started with training Spacy named entity recognition models, and following the basic example described [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-data), where you create training examples by instantiating `Doc` objects and serializing those with `DocBin`.

My custom `preprocess.py` file looks like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nlp = spacy.blank("en")
    counter = 0

    db = DocBin()

    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fp:
        line = fp.readline()
        while line:

            record = MyRecord.build(json.loads(line))

            doc = record.to_spacy_doc(nlp=nlp)
            # internally, something like:
            # # char-level indices
            # ent = doc.char_span(0, 5, label='SOMETHING') 
            # doc.set_ents([ent])

            db.add(doc)

            counter += 1
            # hacky way to save 1000 docs in each DocBin
            if counter == 1000:
                db.to_disk("./train.spacy")
                db = DocBin()

            if counter == 2000:
                db.to_disk("./dev.spacy")
                break
            line = fp.readline()
```

Then run the training script with a command like this:

```sh
python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train train.spacy --paths.dev dev.spacy
```

This seems to work well enough. However, I then read that you can write custom data loader functions by writing and registering a generator that yields instances of `Example` in a process described [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#custom-code-readers-batchers). This interests me, as in theory you could read from larger-than-RAM files during the training loop.

I wrote such a generator myself in `functions.py`, that yields `Example` instances from an external data source (which happens to be custom JSONL from disk) where I have some known entity labels (with char-level indices):

```py
@spacy.registry.readers("corpus_variants.v1")
def stream_data(source: str) -> Callable[[Language], Iterator[Example]]:
    def generate_stream(nlp: Language):
        counter = 0
        with open(source, 'r') as fp:
            line = fp.readline()
            while line:

                record = MyRecord.build(json.loads(line))

                #doc = nlp(record.text)
                doc = nlp.make_doc(record.doc_with_annotations.text)

                entities = [
                    (start, end, label)     # char-level offets (not token-level)
                    for start, end, label, _
                    in record.get_entity_tuples()
                ]

                gold_dict = dict(
                    entities=entities
                )

                example = Example.from_dict(doc, gold_dict)
                yield example

                counter += 1
                # arbitrarily stop at 20 for debugging purposes, but ideally stream the very large file
                if counter > 20:
                    break
                line = fp.readline()
    return generate_stream
```

I also modified `config.cfg` to contain the following:

```
[corpora.dev]
@readers = "corpus_variants.v1"
source = "dev.jsonl"

[corpora.train]
@readers = "corpus_variants.v1"
source = "train.jsonl"
```

When I run the training command:

```sh
python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --code functions.py
```

I get many `UserWarning: [W030] Some entities could not be aligned in the text` warnings. I've read a few posts on the [theory behind these warnings](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/5727), but I am curious as to why this behavior does not occur when I am saving `DocBin`s? Is the alignment actually different or do the warnings occur only when explicitly creating `Example` instances?

I am interested in getting the custom data loader working with this data, but also interested in alternative approaches that essentially allow me to stream arbitrary lines from a (larger-than-RAM) file as training examples.

Finally, what might also be relevant to answering this question is understanding the differences between training a fresh (NER) model from scratch vs. updating an existing one. If I understand Spacy pipelines correctly, there might be some alignment advantages to updating an existing model since the same tokenizer can be used when assembling training examples and during inference.

Comment: Without the details for exactly how the docs are constructed it's very hard to say, but you want to compare the tokenization and `doc.ents` for both methods to see what the differences are.

Comment: Thanks @aab -- it's tough to get succinct example code to demonstrate this, but I spot checked a few of these and `doc.ents` from the `DocBin` example returns the same number of ents and `len(doc)` returns the same number of tokens as `len(entities)` and `len(doc)` from the `Example` example, respectively. This suggests to me the alignment issues are likely present when serializing as `DocBin`, but the warnings just don't show up for some reason. If this is the case, it would be nice to confirm this behavior.

Comment: Depending on how you do the conversion, it's certainly possible that you might not run into this particular warning. The warning is not related to `DocBin`, just how the underlying `Doc` objects are created.