# Train Spacy model with larger-than-RAM dataset

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70367348/spacy-alignment-differences-when-training-with-docbin-vs-custom-data-reading-and) to better understand some of the nuances between training Spacy models with `DocBin`s serialized to disk, versus loading `Example` instances via custom data loading function. The goal was to train a Spacy NER model with more data that can fit into RAM (or at least some way to avoid loading the entire file into RAM). Though the custom data loader seemed like one specific way to accomplish this, I am writing this question to ask more generally:

How can one train a Spacy model without loading the entire training data set file during training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only options are using a custom data loader or setting `max_epochs = -1`. See [the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/training#custom-code-readers-batchers).

Comment: Thanks, @polm23. The docs say:


`-1 means stream train corpus [] rather than loading in memory with no shuffling within the training loop.`

Would setting setting `max_epochs = -1` and using a `.spacy` file (or many `.spacy` files) stream the training data without a custom data loader?

Comment: Yes, it will stream the data.